# Headers in Prepared Requests within a session

Tags: python, python-requests, request-headers

I'm troubleshooting an issue with a POST request. It looks like one of the fields in POST data affects the headers. This is my code:

```
s = requests.Session()

post_data = {...}
different_post_data = {...}

post_200 = requests.Request('POST', url, data=post_data)
post_404 = requests.Request('POST', url, data=different_post_data)

prepped_200 = s.prepare_request(post_200)
prepped_404 = s.prepare_request(post_400)
```

I naively hoped that the prepped requests will be exactly the same as the ones I can inspect by `response.request.headers` but they contain only partial information and only some of the cookies. I know I am missing something as when I then try `s.send(prepped_200)` it fails. Is there a way to see the request exactly as it would be sent by `s.post(url, post_data)`?

Comment: Use a mitm proxy like Telerik Fiddler Classic (Windows) or mitm (Linux) is probably the easiest way to see what’s being sent to your server. You do realise that because you’re using a session the second request actually sent may have cookies that the first didn’t? Also redirections might affect the sequence. A proxy will show you what’s going on.

Comment: Sessions will persist headers set on the session. Read the documentation https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ And the source https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/sessions/